# How to perform Key based queries to Google Datastore from Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-datastore

I manage to make a connection to a Google Cloud Datastore databased. Now I want to get some entities given their Key/Id. Right now I am doing the following:

```
from google.cloud import datastore


client = datastore.Client()
query = client.query(kind='City')
query.key_filter("325899977574122") -> Exception here
```

I get "Invalid key: '325899977574122'".
What could be the cause of error? That Id exist, a city does have that key/Id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it needs to be of type `google.cloud.datastore.key.Key`

https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/queries.html#google.cloud.datastore.query.Query.key_filter

Also, `325899977574122` is probably supposed to be cast to a long

So something like this:

```
client = datastore.Client()
query = client.query(kind='City')
query.key_filter(Key('City', 325899977574122L, project=project))
```

EDIT:

Also if youre trying to retrieve a single id, you should probably use this:

https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/client.html#google.cloud.datastore.client.Client.get

```
client = datastore.Client()
client.get(Key('City', 325899977574122L, project=project))
```

Fetching by ID is faster than doing a query